# singular value decomposition of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0& 1\\0& 0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I'm currently looking for the singular value decomposition of $$\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1 \\
    0       & 0 \\
    0       & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
but I am having a struggle, because $A^TA$ has a 0 singular value, so I cant really use our formula. I have the $V$ and $\sum$ (that is I guess the incorrect way to write the sigma matrix in LaTeX) marices. I have for $U$ only one vector:
$$u_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,1)$$
How do I get one more?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

I thought that since 
$$(0,1,0)A=\sigma_2 A$$
where $\sigma_2=0$, $u_2=(0,1,0)$

and also

$$u_3=u_1\times u_2=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$

I cheated a little bit, I checked it on Wolfram Alpha, but I'm still unsure whether my conclusions are correct.

Comment: $A^T A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. This has an eigenvector of $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ with eigenvalue $2$. So one singular value is $\sqrt{2}$, the others are zero. The right singular vector is $v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and the corresponding left singular vector is $u_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: This is already enough information to write down a reduced SVD. If you need a full SVD, you need two more left singular vectors and one more right singular vector. You can get these by picking two vectors $u_2,u_3$ independent of $u_1$ and running Gram-Schmidt, and similarly picking $v_2$ independent of $v_1$ and running Gram-Schmidt. $v_2$ is almost uniquely determined (up to sign) but $u_2$ and $u_3$ are not at all uniquely determined.

Answer (score 3):

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 0):

A procedure of finding a SVD is

1. Find all eigenvalues of $A^T A$ in decreasing order and unit eigenvectors so that the eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis -> Let's call them $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots$ and $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ (right singular vectors $V$).
2. Normalize all nonzero vectors from $Av_1, Av_2, \ldots$ and put additional unit vectors if necessary so that the resulting vectors form an orthonormal basis (left singular vectors $U$).
3. Then $A V = U S$ where $S$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\sqrt{\lambda_1}, \sqrt{\lambda_2}, \ldots$.
4. As a result, $A = U S V^T$.

In this question, $\lambda_1=2, \lambda_2=0$ and $v_1=(0, 1), v_2=(1, 0)$.

Now $Av_1 = (1, 0, 1)$ and $Av_2 = (0, 0, 0)$, so one of left singular vectors should be $(1/\sqrt{2}, 0, 1/\sqrt{2})$ and you can choose any additional vectors as long as they form an orthonormal basis.

Let $V = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and
$U = \begin{pmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Since $S = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, 
$\quad A = U S V^T$

Comment: If you're going to make $S$ square, then there is no real reason to even include the zero singular value and corresponding singular vectors. It would have been better to just write $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. If you want $U,V$ to be orthogonal matrices (i.e. for their columns to be an orthonormal basis of something), then you need to extend $U$ with one more column, which will make $S$ non-square as in the other answer.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I agree with you, but one advantage of leaving zero entries in S is that we can always write the decomposition in a certain standard form (when A is m-by-n, U is m-by-n, S is n-by-n, and V is n-by-n).

Comment: Eh, that's fair. Personally, I find the standard form where $A$ is $m \times n$, $U$ is $m \times m$, $S$ is $m \times n$, $V$ is $n \times n$ to be more useful for theoretical work. Of course the reduced SVD is the only way to go for numerical work.